# Cloning a mutable member

Tags: java, clone

I have a class `SBContainer` which has a `StringBuffer` member `mySB`. I am implementing `Cloneable` for `SBContainer` like this -

```
SBContainer implements Cloneable {
    public StringBuffer mySB;
    public SBContainer() {
        mySB = new StringBuffer("This is a test string");
    }
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        SBContainer cloned = (SBContainer)super.clone();
        return cloned;
    }
}
```

Now, I create an object `sbc1` for `MyContainer` and it's clone `sbc2`. It looks like the container `mySB` is not cloned; and `sbc1.mySB` and `sbc2.mySB` are pointing to the same `StringBuffer` object. I tested using the following class -

```
public class SBContainerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SBContainer sbc1 = new SBContainer();
        SBContainer sbc2 = null;
        try {
            sbc2 = (SBContainer)sbc1.clone();
        } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sbc1.mySB.append(" ...something appended");
        System.out.println(sbc2.mySB);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The output was: `This is a test string ...something appended`

So, I tried to clone `mySB` like this -

```
cloned.mySB = (StringBuffer)mySB.clone();
```

...and I get this error -

```
SBContainerTest.java:8: clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object
        cloned.mySB = (StringBuffer)mySB.clone();
                                        ^
1 error
```

So, how can I achieve this? How can I clone a mutable member of a class which implements `Cloneable`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuffer` is not `Cloneable`, so you'll have to clone it manually. I suggest something like this in your `clone` method:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    SBContainer cloned = (SBContainer)super.clone();
    cloned.mySB = new StringBuffer(this.mySB);
    return cloned;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose that `mySB` is `final` in `SBContainer`, how to clone it? There is no point in cloning here, of course. But, say I have a final object `lock` for synchronization purpose. If I cannot clone it, when the object1's `lock` is acquired, object2's lock would also get acquired since they are same objects.

Comment: In general, `clone` and `final` are incompatible. You could remove the `final` modifier, but I would recommend simply cloning manually by calling `new SBContainer(new StringBuffer(this.mySB))`.

Comment: Also you're better off avoiding cloning all together and creating your own copy method. Cloning is a bit of a wart.